# React-hook-form register doesn't work with radio input on Safari

Tags: reactjs, cross-browser, react-hook-form

I made a simple form with type=radio using react-hook-form and it works well on Chrome but it doesn't work on Safari.

Here is my code.

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form"

const MemberCheck = () => {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
  } = useForm()
  const onSubmit = ({ isMember }) => console.log({ isMember })
  
  return (
    <div className="member-check">
      <h1>Question1</h1>
      <p>{`Is this person already part of our member?`}</p>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <div className="radio-container">
          <div className="radio-row">
            <input {...register("isMember")} type="radio" value />
            <label>Yes</label>
          </div>
          <div className="radio-row">
            <input {...register("isMember")} type="radio" value={false} />
            <label>No</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default MemberCheck
```

It should submit my answer isMember=true/false but
the console.log in onSubmit shows `{isMember: null}`
This happens only on Safari. works for Firefox and Chrome.
Thanks in advance.